# Поддержка свойства gap

Tags: css, css3

С момента существования свойства **gap**, мне понравилась его полезность и простота в использовании. Но по сей день страшно использовать его. Проверяю его поддержку браузерами на can i use, global  95.42%

В целом часто используемые браузеры не конфликтуют и всё хорошо, но в документациях и на том же habr это свойство упоминается очень редко. На W3C не проверял. Мне хотелось бы знать ваше мнение, стоит ли использовать?

Comment: «ваше мнение» — оффтопик на этом сайте

Comment: Не надо бояться, надо проверять - [@supports](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/@supports)!

Answer (score 1):

Если используете `flex` или `grid`, то используйте `gap`, а если нет - не используйте.

`Flex` и `Grid` уже давно всеми браузерами поддерживаются

Comment: А вот gap — не всеми.

Comment: 93.29% - вполне хватает)). Кстати иногда меня gap раздражает тем, что нужно высчитывать ширину блоков относительно gap. Было бы идеально, если поставив gap: 30px; можно было ширину блоков сделать width: 50%;, а приходится width:calc(50% - 15px);. И это если всего два блока расположены по горизонтали, а если 3 и более, там уже высчитывать сложнее.

Comment: Для кого-то эти 6.71% могут оказаться существенными платёжеспособными клиентами